# Convert multilevel object to query string

Tags: javascript, urlsearchparams

How i can convert object into `location%5Bokrug%5D%5B%5D=38&location%5Bokrug%5D%5B%5D=41`:

```js
let filter = {
    location: {
        okrug: [38, 41]
    }
}
```

`URLSearchParams` does not help:

```js
console.log(new URLSearchParams(filter).toString()) //got location=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

`location%5Bokrug%5D%5B%5D=38&location%5Bokrug%5D%5B%5D=41`

Comment: try `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter))`, first converts the JSON into a string with no whitespace, then encodes it.

Comment: how is this working with a comma instead of a period: `new URLSearchParams(filter),toString()`?

Comment: its typo, sry, fixed)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a query parser library like [qs](https://github.com/ljharb/qs) that has been thoroughly tested.

I included a snippet that uses version 6.11.0 below.

```js
const filter = { location: { okrug: [38, 41] } };
  
console.log(Qs.stringify(filter, { encode: true }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qs/6.11.0/qs.min.js"></script>
```

#### Output

> `location%5Bokrug%5D%5B0%5D=38&location%5Bokrug%5D%5B1%5D=41`

#### Related questions

- [How to generate query string from a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912739/how-to-generate-query-string-from-a-nested-object)
- [Want to convert a nested object to query parameter for attaching to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173848/want-to-convert-a-nested-object-to-query-parameter-for-attaching-to-url)